# Number of points with unbounded curvature...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-topology

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R ^2$ be a smooth (continuously differentiable forever) function.

Let $X$ be the image of $f$ (in the plane).

Say that $x\in X$ has unbounded curvature if there is a sequence of points $x_n\in X$ such that $x_n\to x$ and  $\text{curv}(x_n)\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

For instance, in the image below, $f(0)$ has unbounded curvature, according to my definition.

[image]

My question is, *can $X$ have a dense set of points where the curvature is unbounded*?

Comment: If you're assuming $f$ is only $C^1$, there needn't be curvature at all. The usual definition of curvature will assume twice-differentiability.

Comment: @TedShifrin I want to assume $f$ has derivatives of every order -- or just of order $2$ (would there be a difference in the answer here?)

Comment: Oh, well, if you're assuming $f$ is $C^2$ and $f'\ne 0$ (so you have an immersed curve), then the curvature will be everywhere finite. So what are you actually thinking about there?

Comment: @TedShifrin see edit

Comment: Oh, what you're interested in is, in particular, points $x$ at which the curve fails to be topologically embedded. So start with that point-set question: Can you have a continuous curve which fails to be topologically embedded at a dense set of points?

Comment: @TedShifrin yes that is possible: http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~pyrih/e/e2001v2/s/c0003/s0020/e0050/A.gif , but the curvature is only unbounded at one point

Comment: Hmm ... With that picture I still do not see a *dense* set of bad points.  But I guess we should just think about it this way. Curvature $\kappa$ will be (at least) a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$. How can $\kappa(t_n)\to\infty$ with $f(t_n)$ having lots of convergent subsequences? (Obviously, we need to have $t_n\to\infty$.)